# using a collection of comboboxes to change the Enabled Property

Tags: vb.net, collections, combobox, properties

I am building a large data entry form and want to enable or disable groups of comboboxes based on a checkbox ( if the check box gets checked, the collection of combo boxes get enabled for user input and vice versa ). I want to use collection, because the comboboxes are not always going to be in sequential order ( example : Comboboxes 1-7, then Combobox 12, then 16, and 45-57 ). A collection seems ideal.

I've built the collections, added the comboboxes, and added items to the comboboxes. All the items are there in the comboboxes when I run the Application. I can enable or disable them individually, but I can't enable/disable the comboboxes as a collection.. how can I enable or disable them as a group ?

I can get this to work if I select all the combo boxes in my form, and then run the thru list matching the names against a variable ( as an example, for boxes 1 - 56 ), but that makes using a collection redundant. I am also going to want to output the data, in the collection groups, for later use.

I've been beating my head against the wall for a day or so on this..

## Declare Collection

```
 Dim CablesCollectionBoxes As New Collection
```

## Add Comboboxes to collection

```
CablesCollectionBoxes.Add(ComboBox1)
 CablesCollectionBoxes.Add(ComboBox2)
 CablesCollectionBoxes.Add(ComboBox3)
 .
 <removed for space and readability>
 .
 CablesCollectionBoxes.Add(ComboBox56)
```

## I am trying modify the collection of ComboBoxes to a disabled state, but the code below won't work.

```
for I as integer = 1 to 56
   CablesCollectionBoxes.Item(i) = Disabled 
 next
```

It DOES work if I use this, but I'm not using the collection, I am running thru ALL the comboboxes and matching names :

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 56
    Dim clsCombo As ComboBox = DirectCast(Me.Controls.Find("ComboBox" & i.ToString(), True)(0), ComboBox)
    clsCombo.Enabled = True
Next
```

or this

```
    ComboBox1.Enabled = True
    ComboBox2.Enabled = True
    ComboBox3.Enabled = True
    ComboBox4.Enabled = True
     .
    <removed for space and readability>
     .
    ComboBox56.Enabled = True
```

How do I access the comboboxes as a group, and change the properties ? Did I declare the collection incorrectly ?

Comment: You have to set the preperty of each Control. It can shorter, as `[Your List Collection].ForEach(Sub(c) c.Enabled = False)`. You iterate the elements in the collection anyway. You could build a class object that enables/disables Controls by Group (by *name* or other means) and also builds the collections, to simplify the procedure at run-time. Iterating the single elements is inevitable, if you cannot add them to a single parent container. Binding a property to Settings is possible, but with the `Enabled` property is tricky and IMO, not worth it. Iterating a collection is not exactly a problem

Comment: First things first, don't use that `Collection` class. That's a holdover from VB6 that should not be used in new code. If you want a collection of `ComboBoxes` then use a `List(Of ComboBox)`.

Comment: If the controls are laid out on the form such that the groups are together, you can add `Panels` to the form and then add your `ComboBoxes` to the `Panels`. You can then do away with the collections altogether and use `For Each cb In somePanel.Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that the check box and the enabled property of the combos are in syn when the program starts. Use the designer.

```
Private ComboCollection As New List(Of ComboBox)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    BuildCBCollection()
End Sub

Private Sub BuildCBCollection()
    For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf (ctrl) Is ComboBox Then
            ComboCollection.Add(CType(ctrl, ComboBox))
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    For Each cb In ComboCollection
        cb.Enabled = Not cb.Enabled
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you, I am off and running again.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use collection. Collections are soft-deprecated. `Use List(Of T)`

```vb
Dim comboList As New List(Of ComboBox)()
comboList.Add(cbo1)
comboList.Add(cbo2)
comboList.Add(cbo3)


' Imports System.Linq
comboList.ForEach(Sub(cbo) cbo.Enabled = True)
```

This is as close as you can get.

Now, if you want to have some selective way to enable/disable or whatever, you can use `Tag` property to mark and then it will look like this

```
comboList.Where(Function(cbo) cbo.Tag IsNot Nothing AndAlso CBool(cbo.Tag)).ToList().ForEach(Sub(cbo) cbo.Enabled = True)
```

Comment: Ahh. That's what I was thinking, I was declaring a collection, and I should have been using a combolist. Old way of doing it.